# Adding Children to React Component Dynamically with Rails layouts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I'm working on a Rails app with React using the react-rails gem. I'd like to have a react component in my header (that is in a layout that appears on every page of the app). I'd like that component to have different children depending on the page that I'm on though. Is there a clean way of doing that in React with Rails?

Essentially I have a header that depends on the state of the app for certain pages. More concretely, I want to have a cart component in my header that updates a number when a user puts things in it. But the components where the user can do that only exist on the store page. So I basically want to add the store components only when those pages are loaded and have them connected to the cart compoenent. But am not sure how I can add child components to another component in React.

I'm new to Reactjs, so I might not be thinking about this the right way.

Thanks!

Comment: There isn't a clear question here, what have you tried, what are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in a variable from the Rails page as props to the component

There's a number of ways you could set a variable in your controller depending on the page you are on. You could set a @page variable in the controller and pass that into the component.

```
<%= react_component('NumberThing', {page: @page}, {prerender: true}) %>
```